# Centering moving text on an image with specific height and width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center some moving text on an image. I want the image to be 100% width and 20% height but these sizes mean the text doesn't float in the center of the image and the sizes don't apply correctly to the image.

I took the source code for the floating title and copy pasted it.

This is the original html:

```css
#one {
  height: 20%;
  max-height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

// google font subsetting, see Heydon Pickering's: http://www.sitepoint.com/joy-of-subsets-web- 
fonts/ @import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico&text=Pure');
@import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700&text=css');
@import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script&text=!');
body {
  min-height: 450px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, darken(dodgerblue, 10%), #1f4f96, #1b2949, #000);
}

.stage {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  perspective: 9999px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.layer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: ಠ_ಠ 5s infinite alternate ease-in-out -7.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform: rotateY(40deg) rotateX(33deg) translateZ(0);
}

.layer:after {
  font: 40px/0.65 'Pacifico', 'Kaushan Script', Futura, 'Roboto', 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans- serif;
  content: 'something\A    something!';
  white-space: pre;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  color: darken(#fff, 4%);
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  text-shadow: 4px 0 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .13);
}

$i: 1;
$NUM_LAYERS: 20;
@for $i from 1 through $NUM_LAYERS {
  .layer:nth-child(#{$i}):after {
    transform: translateZ(($i - 1) * -1.5px);
  }
}

.layer:nth-child(n+#{round($NUM_LAYERS/2)}):after {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 3px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .25);
}

.layer:nth-child(n+#{round($NUM_LAYERS/2 + 1)}):after {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 15px dodgerblue;
  text-shadow: 6px 0 6px darken(dodgerblue, 35%), 5px 5px 5px darken(dodgerblue, 40%), 0 6px 6px darken(dodgerblue, 35%);
}

.layer:nth-child(n+#{round($NUM_LAYERS/2 + 2)}):after {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 15px darken(dodgerblue, 10%);
}

.layer:last-child:after {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 17px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .1);
}

.layer:first-child:after {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: none;
}

@keyframes ಠ_ಠ {
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(-40deg) rotateX(-43deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="title-box">
  <div class="stage">
    <img id="one" src="something.jpg" />
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to center the text within the stage, you need to set the top to zero for the layer and then to center the text in the after, you can use `display:flex`:

```css
#one {
  height: 20%;
  max-height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

// google font subsetting, see Heydon Pickering's: http://www.sitepoint.com/joy-of-subsets-web- 
fonts/ @import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico&text=Pure');
@import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700&text=css');
@import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script&text=!');
body {
  min-height: 450px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, darken(dodgerblue, 10%), #1f4f96, #1b2949, #000);
}

.stage {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  perspective: 9999px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.layer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:0;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: ಠ_ಠ 5s infinite alternate ease-in-out -7.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform: rotateY(40deg) rotateX(33deg) translateZ(0);
}

.layer:after {
  font: 40px/0.65 'Pacifico', 'Kaushan Script', Futura, 'Roboto', 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans- serif;
  content: 'something\A    something!';
  white-space: pre;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  color: darken(#fff, 4%);
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  text-shadow: 4px 0 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .13);
  display:flex; 
  justify-content:center; 
  align-items:center;
}

$i: 1;
$NUM_LAYERS: 20;
@for $i from 1 through $NUM_LAYERS {
  .layer:nth-child(#{$i}):after {
    transform: translateZ(($i - 1) * -1.5px);
  }
}

.layer:nth-child(n+#{round($NUM_LAYERS/2)}):after {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 3px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .25);
}

.layer:nth-child(n+#{round($NUM_LAYERS/2 + 1)}):after {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 15px dodgerblue;
  text-shadow: 6px 0 6px darken(dodgerblue, 35%), 5px 5px 5px darken(dodgerblue, 40%), 0 6px 6px darken(dodgerblue, 35%);
}

.layer:nth-child(n+#{round($NUM_LAYERS/2 + 2)}):after {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 15px darken(dodgerblue, 10%);
}

.layer:last-child:after {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 17px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .1);
}

.layer:first-child:after {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: none;
}

@keyframes ಠ_ಠ {
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(-40deg) rotateX(-43deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="title-box">
  <div class="stage">
    <img id="one" src="something.jpg" />
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you are wanting it to be in the middle of the image, then you need to wrap the image in a relative div and move all the layers into there too:

```css
.img-wrapper {
  height: 20%;
  position:relative;
}
#one {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%; 
  object-fit:cover;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}

// google font subsetting, see Heydon Pickering's: http://www.sitepoint.com/joy-of-subsets-web- 
fonts/ @import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico&text=Pure');
@import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700&text=css');
@import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script&text=!');
body {
  min-height: 450px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, darken(dodgerblue, 10%), #1f4f96, #1b2949, #000);
}

.stage {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.layer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: ಠ_ಠ 5s infinite alternate ease-in-out -7.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform: rotateY(40deg) rotateX(33deg) translateZ(0);
  z-index:2;
}

.layer:after {
  font: 40px/0.65 'Pacifico', 'Kaushan Script', Futura, 'Roboto', 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans- serif;
  content: 'something\A    something!';
  white-space: pre;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  color: darken(#fff, 4%);
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  text-shadow: 4px 0 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .13);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

$i: 1;
$NUM_LAYERS: 20;
@for $i from 1 through $NUM_LAYERS {
  .layer:nth-child(#{$i}):after {
    transform: translateZ(($i - 1) * -1.5px);
  }
}

.layer:nth-child(n+#{round($NUM_LAYERS/2)}):after {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 3px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .25);
}

.layer:nth-child(n+#{round($NUM_LAYERS/2 + 1)}):after {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 15px dodgerblue;
  text-shadow: 6px 0 6px darken(dodgerblue, 35%), 5px 5px 5px darken(dodgerblue, 40%), 0 6px 6px darken(dodgerblue, 35%);
}

.layer:nth-child(n+#{round($NUM_LAYERS/2 + 2)}):after {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 15px darken(dodgerblue, 10%);
}

.layer:last-child:after {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 17px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .1);
}

.layer:first-child:after {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: none;
}

@keyframes ಠ_ಠ {
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(-40deg) rotateX(-43deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="title-box">
  <div class="stage">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img id="one" src="something.jpg" />
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="layer"></div>
      <div class="layer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving or not you need something like this.

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
  <img src="something.jpg">

  <span>some sample text</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.container img{
  width: 100%;
  height:20%;
}

.container span{
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height:20px;
  background-color: red;
  left: calc(500px / 2 - 75px);
  top:calc(100px / 2 - 10px);
}
```

You can always write custom css animations,
[like this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)